# Formula field is getting error with extra ,

Tags: apex, soql, formula

Hi friends i have formul ain custom object and i am try to group based on a number field.But i am gettig error like ,

Please help my validation rule.

```
IF(Net_Promoter_Score__c < 7, "Detractor"), IF(Net_Promoter_Score__c > 8, 
                                                "Promoter"), "Passive"))
```

I'm getting error like

> Error: Syntax error. Extra ','

Answer (score 4):

You misplaced some parentheses, which confused the compiler. Here's the correct version:

```
IF(Net_Promoter_Score__c < 7, "Detractor", 
  IF(Net_Promoter_Score__c > 8, "Promoter", "Passive"))
```

Generally speaking, if you have a different number of `(` and `)` in a formula, then you have a mistake somewhere. In your original formula, you had 2 `(` and 4  `)`, which was incorrect.

If statements are in the form `IF(Condition, TrueValue, FalseValue)`. When you need to chain them together, they take place of the TrueValue/FalseValue places, like this:

```
If(Condition, 
  If(Condition, TrueValue, FalseValue), 
  If(Condition, TrueValue, FalseValue)
)
```

Just remember that the left and right parentheses should always match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
IF(Net_Promoter_Score__c < 7, "Detractor",IF(Net_Promoter_Score__c > 8,"Promoter","Passive"))
```